# Google Cloud Storage: Download filename contains path in bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm uploading a file with firebase storage to some/path/file.txt
Later I get a download url and offer a download via link in browser. When a user downloads the file, it is named file.txt

Now I modify this file with a cloud function via gcloud storage. Im reuploading it with:

```
bucket.upload(localfile, {destination: 'some/path/file.txt'});
```

When now a user downloads the file the suggested filename in the browser is: some%2path%2file.txt

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, set the `Content-Disposition` header of your file to only contain `file.txt`. Something like:

```
bucket.upload(localFile, {
  destination: 'some/path/file.txt'
  metadata: {
    contentDisposition: 'attachment; filename="file.txt"'
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey Mike, is there a way to do it when downloading the file?

Comment: @Mike, 
1. i have set contentDisposition: 'attachment ; filename = "file_name.dsv"'.
2. Using download url from metaData[0].mediaLink.
3. When opening link in from step2, the file has whole path and not mentioned in step 1
4. FYI:The content disposition is saved in metadata.